# SQL Login failed when enableviewstate = false

Tags: sql-server, gridview, asp.net-2.0, viewstate

Good day,

I'm having a problem with asp.net 2.0 viewstate.

Basically, I want to disable the viewstate for a gridview. However, when I do so, as soon as there is a post-back, before even getting into Page_Load, I get a 'Login failed for user sa ...'.

If I enable the viewstate back, everything runs smoothly.

In PageLoad, I set the connection strings to all the SqlDataSource, but as I said, the error comes even before the PageLoad.

In PageLoad, I tried to do something like : MyGridView.DataSourceId = "MySqlDataSource" but with no luck. I'm running out of ideas.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Please tell me you don't actually have a web app that's authenticating to your database using the sa account...

Comment: We were young, and foolish, once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it earlier in the page lifecycle.

If you are developing an ASP.NET website and don't understand the page lifecycle, RUN, DO NOT WALK, and read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Try setting the data source during the Page_Init event.